# Using information from a reference pointer to fill a vector

Tags: c++, function, vector, fill

My goal is to build a function that takes a list of integers and compares them to each other. Basically, if the numbers in the positions before and after the current position match, the current number becomes (or stays) 0. Otherwise, it becomes (or stays) 1.

The code must assume there is a zero before the first, and after the last value, which is why there are those "if-else" statements outside the for loop. The update must happen all at once, which is why there's a second vector to store the new values (`x`) that the main vector (`houses`) will be set to at the end.

My plan was to take the values passed to the function and fill a vector with them. However, I've never seen this done before (even though I'm less than 3 months away from my Bachelor's degree...thank you, Strayer).

How do I fill the vector with the list stored in the referenced memory location?

Note:

- I used `cout << *states;` as a way to try and see what the code sees when I reference the location, when I realized it wasn't working, but all it returns is a single integer. Could someone help me understand how this works, and how to fill the vector with the values?
- Also, I know it would be more efficient to use `push_back()` instead of the `.at(i)=` method, but I was just trying everything I could to figure out the problem, and wound up there when I gave up.)

```
vector<int> cellCompete(int* states, int days) 
{
    vector<int> houses;
    vector<int> x;
    x.resize(8);
    cout << *states;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<8; i++){
        houses.push_back(*states);
        cout << houses.at(i) << endl;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<days; ++i) {        
        if (houses.at(1)==0) {
            x.at(0)=0;
        }
        else{
            x.at(0)=1;
        }
        for (unsigned int y=1; y<7; y++){
            if (houses.at(y-1)==houses.at(y+1)){
                x.at(y)=0;
            }
            else{
                x.at(y)=1;
            }
        }
        if (houses.at(6)==0){
            x.at(7)=0;
        }
        else{
            x.at(7)=1;
        }
        houses=x;        
    }
    return houses;
}
```

Comment: how do you call hte function? I suppose `int* states` is a pointer to the first element of an array, right? Why dont you use `std::vector` also for `states` ?

Comment: I wish I knew. The assignment only let me see this function. I wasn't allowed to look at main, or how the integers are actually obtained. int* states is supposed to be a list of integers that gets passed, but that's all I know.

Comment: you must have a better description of the task (or screw the task), when you get a pointer to an array you also need to know the size of the array, otherwise you cannot do much with the pointer. `states` is not a list of integers, it is just a pointer to a single integer.

Comment: assuming there is an array and `states` does point to the first element, then you get other elements via `states[n]` just as with an array, while `*states` will only get you the first element

Comment: I tried states.at(i) 
Is that what you mean? Or is the syntax literally states[i]?

Comment: a pointer has no method `at`. `x[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(x+i)`, ie the pointer to the first element `x` is advanced by `i` steps and then dereferenced. If find it difficult to give a concise answer, when you also dont really know what `states` is

Comment: Got it, so the command I was looking for was either states[n] or *states[n]. It's still so frustrating that I've never seen an asterisk used like that, or an argument passed to a function in this way. I appreciate the help.

Comment: well, no it is not `*states[n]`, that would dereference twice. `*x` wont work if `x` is already and `int`. Dont worry, passing arrays like that is rather uncommon in C++, you would rather use a `std::vector` which is much easier to work with. Using c-arrays in C++ is mainly for "educational" purposes

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is to build a function that takes a list of integers and
>   compares them to each other.

Reading your code,  I understand that the "*list of integers*" is in fact an *array* that is passed as a pointer, and that days is the number of integers in the array:

```
vector<int> cellCompete(int* states, int days)
```

Unfortunately, in your loop you always append to the vector `*state`, which in you case would be the first array of the integer.  If the pointer points to an array, you may either increment it to point to the next element, or just index it like you would do for an array:

```
vector<int> houses;
vector<int> x(8);   // you can get the right size at construction
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<8; i++){
    houses.push_back(states[i]);
    cout << houses[i] << endl;
}
```

THe question I can't answer:  is there a reason for using a hardcoded size of `8` ?  shouldn't it be `days` instead ?

With this hint, I leave you the rest of your exercise, in order to facilate your learning experience ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid not. There will always be 8 states. Days is the number of times I go through and compare all the values and update them. The program's description said it was a "list of integers" so I don't know if it's a vector, a list, or just several inputs.